# Rails combining RESTful methods in a new controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, view, controller, nested

I have a rails app where `users` create `projects`. Currently these are nested, and are completed as separate actions (A `user` registers, and then from the `project` dashboard creates a new `project`).

To improve conversions (as well as track conversions from adwords and facebook) I want to create a new view called `getting_started` whereby a `user` will register and create a `project` in one step from a single view.

In terms of best practice, should I create a new controller for this, rather than just slapping a new view in `users`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'm not very experienced in this field but as far as I worked,

To create a new controller  for a single function, i.e getting_started which is 100% related to an existing controller doesn't make sense.
I 'll advise to place in the existing controller.

If we talk about efficiency, these will take exactly same time.

Comment: Well, it's not 100% related. In getting started you create a user AND a project. So it's some middle ground between the two. This warrants its own controller.

Comment: Yes, as Sergio said. The two controllers it relates to are the users devise controller `Users::RegistrationsController` and the `ProjectsController`

Comment: thanks for your precious advise.
But I 'm saying these same in terms of model User as User has many projects.
write this in user model: accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true.
and moreover, there are not complex functionalities for you have to make separate controller. 
correct me if I 'm wrong.

Comment: Yes you're right @MuhammadFaisalIqbal. It would pretty much be `new` and `create` methods in the `GettingStartedController`. The `create` method would create the `user` and `project` on Submit, redirect to a `thankyou` view for around 3 seconds to allow conversion tracking before redirecting to the dashboard.

Comment: @Stephen: how does that differ from your regular user creation? does it display "thank you" page as well? And redirects to dashboard too?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The normal user create action simply redirects to the dashboard once registered. The new action would create the user and the project, and would display the thank you page before redirecting (which allows me to track conversions).

Comment: Looking at the logical flow of the new controller, I think it would actually make more sense to include it in the user registration controller, as it's simply an alternative way for people to become users. Having a problem with creating multiple registration "routes" for devise, but that will be a new question! Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion better way is create another controller. Then you have better atomization of code. Which is easier to refactor. You can inherit this controller, and use `super` for creating user.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `getting_started` as an alternative to `users#new`, so you could add it as a new action to `UsersController` and add another action to respond to the POST and create a user with a nested project (I'm assuming you are filling in some form and that you are accepting nested attributes in your `User` model).

No need to create a new controller and inherit from it in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, I did decide to go with this option thank you. I've marked Muhammads answer as right though just as he suggested it first. Thanks!