# Rails similar form fields across multiple views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, partial-views

This question expands on my earlier question posted [Rails combining RESTful methods in a new controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996290/rails-combining-new-restful-methods-in-a-new-view). With my rails web app, a user registers and creates a project. For conversion tracking, I am creating a `getting_started` view that will allow people to register and create a project in a single action (on a single page).

I have the issue now that especially for the `projects`, I will have form fields sitting on two views, namely the project partial `_form` that renders on the `new`, and `update` views. And secondly a form for the user and project details on the `getting_started` view. I feel like I'm duplicating a lot of code, and rails has a simpler way I'm just not seeing. I also change the `project` fields quite regularly and would like a single point to update the form for both the `project` `_form` as well as the `getting_started` `_form`.

I've read that partial views, in partial views can hinder performance, and I also don't think you can simply include form fields in a partial, and render them in a form (will throw out an error asking what "f" means I assume?).

Any suggestions how best to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you looking for `accepts_nested_attributes_for :project` in your user class and something like this for your form:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :project do |builder| %>
   <%= render :partial => "project_form", :locals =>  { f: builder } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It'll allow you to use same form in non-nested view with:

```
<%= form_for @project do |builder| %>
   <%= render :partial => "project_form", :locals =>  { f: builder } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Cool let me try that! Thanks. Out of interest, does the `f.submit` button from the `projects_form` partial then get used as the submit button for the new `<%= form_for @user do |f| %> ...` getting_started form? Ie: I don't need a submit button on the form for this new `getting_started` view because it will pull through the submit button from the `fields_for :project' partial that we're rendering?

Comment: You better leave submit button to the topmost form. As you use nested attributes your topmost form that will send data to a user, will also submit data for nested child forms. Read more [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).